# How to combine multiple variables in a single array

Tags: php, arrays

```
    $arrray = array(
        $this->_SmailerTyle => "PHPMailer",
        $this->_SsendMail   => "smtp",
        $this->from         => "arun.r@infinitisoftware.net",
        $this->to           => "example@gmail.com",
        $this->subject      => "This is example subject",
        $this->message      => "This is example message",
        );
        print_r($arrray);
```

Any one help to convert a single array in multiple variables.

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: No Hemant But my out put ```Array ( [] => This is example message )```

Comment: remove `$this->` and write `'message'`

Comment: As it is trying to use `$this->...` as the index for each value, I assume that either these values are empty or do not exist.  This then means that each value is overwriting the previous one and you end up with the array your getting.

Comment: Thank you for your response @NigelRen, this is one of key point for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

find in your code where you are assigning values to the following properties

```
$this->_SmailerTyle
$this->_SsendMail
$this->from
$this->to
$this->subject
$this->message
```